# Touchscreen on Surface Laptop 4 Does not Work

Tags: dual-boot, touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Surface Laptop 4 along with my Window OS.

After I did the steps from here (https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup) my laptop's keyboard and mousepad works (which was not the case before). However the touchscreen is still not working.

uname -a gives me "Linux diana 5.14.15-surface ..."

What do I have to do to make my touchscreen work?

Comment: You can create a GitHub issue at https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add enough details to identify an adequate answer , Also try to organise this a bit so that the reader has a little bit interest in reading the question.